# How to draw a triangle by two(or three) given angles with angles written at each corners in actionscript ?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, geometry, actionscript-2, angle

I tried to google it but couldn't find a solution.there are method to draw a triangle with one given angle and two lengths .but i want to draw triangle with given two angles.Can some one guild me..

Comment: Draw a single pixel and say it's a zero-sized triangle with these angles

Comment: I am new to ActionScript Can you explain..Please ?

Comment: I can't code in actionscript, sorry. I can only give you algorithmic advice and point out the deficiencies in your specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A triangle is defined correctly only by 2 sides and angle between them, 3 sides, or 1 side and both angles containing that side. Using three angles you can only define a set of triangles. The first commenter said draw a pixel, and he's mathematically correct, as a triangle with infintely small sides, but with 3 correct angles, will be displayed as a single dot. So, you need to define at least one side before you can get a correct displayed triangle.

Comment: Thank you for answering.Sorry for my English in the question.Thats I want..I want to draw a triangle with two given angles and one side(given the line length)..can you help me out.